# Stop a running c program when this script detects a change in the file

Tags: c, linux, bash

does anyone know how I could edit this bash script to stop the current c programming running and start it even if the c program is doing something still. Currently if the program is finished it will recompile and rerun the c program but if the program is doing something still when I save the source code it wont stop it and restart
im on linux mint if that changes anything

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Which c file to watch?: ' file_name
old_file_sig=$(stat -c %Z $file_name)
while true
do
  new_file_sig=$(stat -c %Z c.c)
  if [[ "$new_file_sig" != "$old_file_sig" ]]; then

        gcc $file_name -o $file_name.o && ./$file_name.o
        old_file_sig=$new_file_sig
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Will the command `kill` help you? Please read its documentation or man page.

Comment: No because the kill command will never run as it cant detect changes in the file whilst the program is running.

Comment: Run program in background and save it's job id or pid. Kill it by job id or pid when needed. Also you can use inotify to track changes. Not related to the question: files named with suffix `.o` usually are object files, not executable binaries.

Comment: You might need to _add_ a kill command to your script, when it detects a new version.

Comment: to detect filesystem changes in linux, you need the kernel's help.  use https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the same polling method (checking every second whether the source code has changed, and if so recompile and exec), I would just

- run program in background, so your script can still continue polling for change while program runs
- kills every background jobs (from this script only, of course) before starting a new one

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Which c file to watch?: ' file_name
old_file_sig=$(stat -c %Z $file_name)
while true
do
  new_file_sig=$(stat -c %Z c.c)
  if [[ "$new_file_sig" != "$old_file_sig" ]]; then
        expid=$(jobs -p -r)
        [[ "$expid" ]] && kill $expid
        gcc $file_name -o $file_name.o && { ./$file_name.o & }
        old_file_sig=$new_file_sig
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

In the (unlikely) event if program has terminated between the moment when `jobs -p -r` get its pid, and the moment when `kill` killed it, you may get an error message from kill.

You could also replace those 2 lines by a silent kill

```bash
#!/bin/bash
  if [[ "$new_file_sig" != "$old_file_sig" ]]; then
        kill $(jobs -p -r) 2> /dev/null
        gcc $file_name -o $file_name.o && { ./$file_name.o & }
        old_file_sig=$new_file_sig
  fi
```

It kills everytime the background jobs. Even when there is none, which would makes kill complains about it, but we redirect complains to /dev/null.

Note that I tried to answer staying as close as your initial solution I could. I doesn't mean that I find this solution optimal.

Firstly, it is quite strange to name an executable file.o as you seem to do. `.o` files are object files for separated compilation. They are meant to be linked afterward to form an executable file (usually .exe on windows, and without any extension on linux, tho this is just a convention on linux, and nothing forbids you to call executable files `file.o` or `file.png` if you wish to do so)

Secondly, the polling is generally speaking a bad idea. A bad idea that I often use myself, because of easiness, or because I consider the cpu time wasted negligible. But it is always worth wondering if it is avoidable.

Here, a solution based on `inotifywait` for example avoids it

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Which c file to watch?: ' file_name
while true
do
  gcc $file_name -o $file_name.o && { ./$file_name.o & }
  inotifywait -qq -e modify $file_name
  kill $(jobs -p -r) 2> /dev/null
done
```

Explanation

- I start the process first, so that when starting script, program is run without waiting for file modification
- They, regardless of whether the program in background has finished or not, inotifywait stays blocked until $file_name has been modified
- When it is, kill kills background job if there is any (so if modification of $file_name occurred before the program run was finished). Otherwise it will silently complains in /dev/null
- a new loop compiles and starts the program again,...

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer ill will test it all out shortly and let you know how I go.